# Glossary 'List style', how reduce the space between definitions, and formatting matters

Tags: glossaries, books

everybody.
I'm new to the site, so I greet everyone.
Sorry for my English: I'm not mother language so, I really I appeal to your patience.

My problem consists in difficulties to format my glossaries in a book.
I’m using the “LIST style”, and I’d like to reduce the fixed space between the definitions. 
I tried in many ways but I wasn’t able to find a solutions. I’m worrying it’s not applicable to the style I’m using. 
This is the (simplified) code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % enable Cork Encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[greek.ancient,latin,italian]{babel}
\languageattribute{latin}{withprosodicmarks}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}
\setglossarystyle{list}
%\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\newglossary*{prova}{Glossario del primo capitolo}
\newglossary*{prova2}{Glossario del secondo capitolo}

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
    \setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]% 
        \glspostdescription\space (\textit{Pag. ##2}): %
        \small{\glossentrydesc{##1}} }%
}

\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{}%dovrebbe sopprimere il salto pagina prima del glossario

\makenoidxglossaries 
\glsaddall % sistema i numeri di pagina

\input{file-glossario}

\title{Prova glossario}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter                           
\maketitle                             
\mainmatter

\setglossarystyle{mylist} 

\chapter{prova}
    non  un \gls{Pippo} qualsiasi. Intorno gira abbaiando \gls{Pluto}, e fanno chiasso \gls{Qui}, \gls{Quo} e \gls{Qua}.

    \printnoidxglossary[type=prova]

\chapter{secondo capitolo}
    un tentativo con la parola \gls{Definizione} che non riesce a comprendere tutte le \glspl{Definizione}, e c'è il libero \gls{Arbitrio}.
    Tra i colori e le loro \glspl{Definizione}, c'è pure l'antico termine  \glsuseri{Rubro}.

    \printnoidxglossary[type=prova2]

\end{document}
```

As you can see I use an external .tex to include the definitions.
I've also renewed the style, but it has no impact on the line spacing.
can anyone suggest something to me?

Additional question: do you know how to format the golssaies' titles'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify: I think that the "LIST style" in *Glossaries* is a **description list environment** that probably could me modified using the *enumitem package's commands*. Maybe someone could explain me something about it...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution on my own.

I post it  because it could be useful to someone in the future.
Basically, I discovered that in **glossaries-extra**, the *LIST STYLE* is a *description itemize's enviroment*, so I applied the **enumitem package**, and its commands.

As I don't have other itemized lists in the document, I used a global command, and it worked correctly.
This is the additional code:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{itemsep=0.1ex, leftmargin=0cm,rightmargin=0cm}
```

The *leftmargin* and *rightmargin* command work on the horizontal space, and I used them to align the *descriptions* to the borders.

In real, looking to my question, the correct command should have been the following:

```
\setlist[description]{noitemsep}
```

which effectively suppresses any space in the list.